# pass a value of the form from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller, parameter-passing

how do i pass the value of the form, which is (i assume) a string of date to the controller...

here is my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { $("FORM").submit(); },
        altField: ".alternate"
    });

});

</script>
@model IEnumerable<CorReservation.Models.Reservation>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div class="divRightSide">

<div>
    <div class="datepicker">
    </div>
    <form action="/" title="fff">
    <input type="text" class="alternate" readonly="readonly" />
    </form>
</div>
// do something eg.  foreach (var item in Model)
        { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)}
```

here is my controller: i want to pass the date selected from the datepicker to the controller and then the controller would return an Ienumerable of reservations...

```
    DateTime date = System.DateTime.Now;
    private ReservationEntities db = new ReservationEntities();

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string dateInput)
    {

        date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInput);

        var reservations = db.Reservations.Where(r=> r.Date ==date).Include(r => r.Employee).Include(r => r.Room).OrderByDescending(r => r.Date);

        return View(reservations);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this. Make the form input name attribute match the expected attribute in your controller.

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="alternate" readonly="readonly" name="dateInput" />
```

Or if there's going to be a lot of input values, use a Model.

Comment: there's only a single value... what should my controller look like?

Comment: Your controller is fine. The name of your variable in the controller must match the name of the postback value.

Comment: Yes. If you have dateInput on your textbox and as your controller parameter, MVC will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It's automatically done based on the 'name' attribute of the HTML fields you want to submit.

Change your form to

```
<form action="/" title="fff">
    <input name="dateInput" type="text" class="alternate" readonly="readonly"  />
</form>
```

And it should work just like that.

Also, as you are using Razor syntax, you could use the Razor HTML helpers like so

```
@model IEnumerable<CorReservation.Models.Reservation>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div class="divRightSide">

<div>
    <div class="datepicker">
    </div>
    @using(@Html.BeginForm("<your controller name>", "<your action name e.g. Index>"){
      Html.TextBox("dateInput", "", new { @readonly="readonly", @class="alternate" })
    }
</div>
// do something eg.  foreach (var item in Model)
        { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)}
```

Comment: @RojBeraña Oops use  Html.TextBox("dateInput", "", new { @readonly="readonly", @class="alternate" })